# How to update a variable of an object of a class in javascript by passing an callback to another function in a separate object

Tags: javascript

How can I update a variable of an object of a particular class by passing an callback to another function inside a separate object. Here in the code in the class Example when I make an object of it and then call its callOtherMethod the console.log made by the updateArr() method shows this.arr as undefined. This is an example of the problem that I faced. Thank you for help

```
class Example{
    constructor(){
        this.arr = [];
        this.index = 2;
    }
    updateArr(str){
        this.arr[this.index] = str;
        console.log(this.arr)
    }
    callOtherMethod(){
        this.index = 1;
        anotherObject.method(this.updateArr)
    }
}

anotherObject= {
    method : (callback) =>{
        callback('Hello')
    }
}

const ex = new Example();
ex.callOtherMethod()
//logs this.arr undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass `this.updateArr` and execute it in your `method` function:

```
method : (callback) =>{
  callback('Hello')
}
```

... the `this` that gets bound to `updateArr` gets lost, as the calling context to `callback` is not specified.

To fix this, you can pass a special version of your `this.updateArr` to your `anotherObject.method()` method, which has its `this` explicitly bound to it using the [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) function. The `.bind()` method will return a new function with the `this` being bound to be the first argument that you pass.

See example below:

```js
class Example {
  constructor() {
    this.arr = [];
    this.index = 2;
  }
  updateArr(str) {
    this.arr[this.index] = str;
    console.log(this.arr)
  }
  callOtherMethod() {
    this.index = 1;
    // pass a function with the `this` being bound to the current object
    anotherObject.method((...args) => this.updateArr(...args))
  }
}

anotherObject = {
  method: (callback) => {
    callback('Hello')
  }
}

const ex = new Example();
ex.callOtherMethod();
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
anotherObject.method((...args) => this.updateArr(...args))
```

This will pass a function into `arnotherObject.method()` which when executed will run:

```
this.updateArr(...args)
```

since the `this` here refers to your object instance (as arrow function's don't have their own `this` binding) you will be able to call your instance's `updateArr` method.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use the traditional approach of binding the object to the function as suggested in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63610625/11057988).

Or also pass the function name as a string along with the original object. And then access the function using the property of the object:

```js
class Example{
    constructor(){
        this.arr = [];
        this.index = 2;
    }
    updateArr(str){
        this.arr[this.index] = str;
        console.log(this.arr)
    }
    callOtherMethod(){
        this.index = 1;
        anotherObject.method(this, "updateArr")
    }
}

anotherObject= {
    method : (obj, callback) =>{
        obj[callback]('Hello');
    }
}

const ex = new Example();
ex.callOtherMethod();
```